# Angular Search function after click

Tags: angular, search, service, onclick, angular-material

I'm trying to filter objects in the table after a click.

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchValue)">
  <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="nameFilter" [value]="searchValue">
  </mat-form-field> 

  <button mat-raised-button class="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

TS

```
onSubmit(){

    this.ListService.getList(this.currentUser().my_token, this.form.value).then(res => {
      this.nameFilter.valueChanges.subscribe(name => {
      this.filterValue.name = name;
      this.dataSource.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filterValue);

      });
    })
  }
```

SERVICE

```
getList(token, frm) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      return this.http.post<any>("my_path",
        {
          'token': token,
          'frm': 
          {
            'id': frm.id,
            'name' : frm.name
          }
    })
```

When I enter a name in my input and click on the search button, I want all the names that match the input names to appear in the table.
Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 way binding for `nameFilter` and call `onSubmit` on button click. like below

```
<form [formGroup]="form" >
  <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="nameFilter" [(ngModel)]="searchValue" >
  </mat-form-field> 

  <button mat-raised-button class="search" (click)="onSubmit(searchValue)">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the type="submit" of a button.

```
<form [formGroup]="form"  (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(searchValue)">
  <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="nameFilter" [value]="searchValue">
  </mat-form-field> 

  <button mat-raised-button class="search">Search</button>
</form>
```